# Java web application- How to send email through the same server?

Tags: java, email

I have a java web application system. In the system, there are a number of users. For example, there are 10 different users in the system.

Each user have the feature to send a email to the other users within the same system. From what I read,it seems Java Mail API is an option but it's for sending to email client server instead.

What I want is when the recipient user logs in to the account, he should be able to view the email within that system.

Can anyone give me some suggestion or what to look at to achieve this?

Comment: if it's only for internal use, what's to stop you from building your own e-mail system?basically: write the messages to your own DB, link them to the right users, and have a listener constantly checking whether you've got new mails to read

Comment: The problem is this in my current system, the way it works is I enter the recipient email address along with the subject and content of the email and hit send button. And some user's in the user table does not have email registered. So is there a way to send to the recipient i want?

Comment: You just need something which all users have. That can be combination of first name + surname, a username or just the ID. You could also implement a user selector, which just shows all available users (if that's legally possible in your usecase)

Comment: @dunni In this case, do I need to use anys ort of API still like Java Mail API or just vanilla?

Comment: No, all you need is DB access. Whatever API/framework you use for that.

Comment: I'm using persistence java for db access. Assuming I can get every user to have email as mandatory and since I have a user table which contains email column of the user, how do i actually "send" it?

Comment: I'll post an answer with some hints and information.

Comment: @Daredevil you don't "send" anything. you add a record with the "email" to a table, and make sure the users have a client installed which shows a notification when they detect a new message with that user as destination

Comment: I see. So most logical way of doing this is adding a new table to store the record with the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to implement an in-application messaging system could look like this:

You create a table for your messages. That table could have columns like message id, recipient (e.g. email adress) and content.

When a user creates a message, you store that in the new table.

When another user logs in, you make a query on that table, if there are any messages for that user (which have the users adress in the recipient column), and show those messages to the user.
Additionally, when creating the message, you can create an event which could trigger then a push notification. There are several 3rd party providers, where you can just call an API, and the user would get a notification on his phone (you would need then at least a phone number or other identifiers for that user).

Comment: If I understand your answer clearly, I have a page which contains `Recipient: abc@example.com , Subject: example , and Content: Random messages` and when I click send, it should store these into my table. Then when the user abc logs in, let's say there's an option for the user to click inbox and it should show all the messages to him,then I make a query on the table to retrieve the record,is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's how you can do it.

Comment: Ok, in my case, would it be neccessary to store the all 3 objects i mentioned above to the table? I would  need 3 columns for that.

Comment: Well, you need to store the information that you want to show. Recipient is mandatory, otherwise you don't know who the message belongs to. Subject can be discussed if it's necessary, and a message without content doesn't make sense.

Comment: and yes, make one column for each separate piece of information. Don't put everything together in one column

Comment: And it would also be neccessary for the recipient to know the messages come from which sender. How does one handle that?

Comment: Create another column where you store the sender, when the message is created.